# iptables: what is a chain?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, netfilter

I've been reading about iptables for hours and I still don't understand what is it that they're calling a "chain".
I see this word everywhere in the doc and in tutorials and it's still fuzzy to me what they're talking about.
What's a chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [chain](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Iptables#chains) is a sequence of rules applied in order.

There are three built-in chains (`INPUT`, `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD`) and you can create your own to streamline processing for e.g. specific packet types.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm starting to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Chain is nothing but sequence of filter rules maintained by iptables.

- INPUT Chain : For packets coming into the system or destined for the
  system.
- FORWARD Chain : For packets travelling (being routed) through    the
  system.
- OUTPUT Chain : For packets leaving the system or    originating from
  the system.

To know more about IPTABLES, Visit an article my [Linux Blog](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/05/iptables-linux-firewall.html):